# MongoDB match based on multiple array fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, match

Suppose I have the following documents:

```
{
  "_id": "ID1",
  "A": [
    {
    "a": "abc",
    "b": true
    },
    {
    "a": "abc",
    "b": false
    },
    {
    "a": "def",
    "b": true
    }
  ]
}

{
  "_id": "ID2",
  "A": [
    {
    "a": "abc",
    "b": false
    },
    {
    "a": "abc",
    "b": false
    },
    {
    "a": "def",
    "b": true
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I adjust my query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"A.a": "abc"}},
  {$project: {A: 1}}
])
```

So that I match only documetns where there is at least one object in `A` where `A.a=abc AND A.b=true`? In this example the outcome would be just:

```
{
  "_id": "ID1",
  "A": [
    {
    "a": "abc",
    "b": true
    },
    {
    "a": "abc",
    "b": false
    },
    {
    "a": "def",
    "b": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$elemMatch`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { A: { $elemMatch: { a: "abc", b: true }}},
  { $project: { A: 1 }}
])
```

can use `find` query as well

```
db.collection.find(
  { A: { $elemMatch: { a: "abc", b: true }},
  { A: 1 }
)
```